# Data extraction via API - Are data records deleted in source?

Tags: google-analytics, extract

When I pull data using the Google Analytics API, is it possible for records to be completely deleted in the source or are deleted records flagged? I would need to clarify this as part of our SCD historization.

Did not try anything yet, just want to clarify...

Comment: Have you checked Google's documentation?  If it doesn't say, I'd think that only Google itself knows the answer to this question and you'd have to ask them directly.